# Write numpy array to buffer as jpeg

Tags: numpy, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, streaming, mjpeg

I have a program which returns a stream of np.uin8 arrays.  I would like to now broadcast these to a website being hosted by that computer.

I planned to do this by injecting the code in [this](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming) documentation by replacing the line `camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')` with `output.write(<numpy_array_but_jpeg>)`.  The documentation for `start_recording` states that if the `write()` method exists it will write the data in the requested format to that buffer.
I can find lots of stuff online that instructs on how to save a `np.uint8` as a jpeg, but in my case I want to write that data to a buffer in memory, and I won't want to have to save the image to file and then read that file into the buffer.

Unfortunately, changing the output format of the `np.uint8` earlier in the stream is not an option.

Thanks for any assistance.  For simplicity I have copied the important bits of code below

```
class StreamingOutput(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.frame = None
    self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
    self.condition = Condition()

def write(self, buf):
    if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
        # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
        # clients it's available
        self.buffer.truncate()
        with self.condition:
            self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
            self.condition.notify_all()
        self.buffer.seek(0)
    return self.buffer.write(buf)

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
```

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. You want to *"broadcast to a website"*?

Comment: I was planning on using a PubSub system, where this part of the program would be the publisher, broadcasting the image.  I have a solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV has functions to do this

`retval, buf = cv.imencode(ext,img[, params])`

lets you write an array to a memory buffer.

This [example](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq/blob/master/examples/pub_sub_broadcast.py) here shows a basic implementation of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
img_encode = cv.imencode('.png', img)[1]
  
# Converting the image into numpy array
data_encode = np.array(img_encode)
  
# Converting the array to bytes.
byte_encode = data_encode.tobytes()
```